# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After reading all others questions about the HY093 i cant figure out what is causing the error.

i have 3 file to proses INSERT query :
1. controller.php
2. module.php
3. query.php

**controller.php**

```
$this->ModelProduct = new ModelProduct($this->db);
$param_new = "':code' =>124,':name' =>".$_POST['post_name']."";
$so_result = $this->ModelProduct->AddNew($param_new);
```

**module.php**

```
define('tbl_all_product','product');
define('field_product','code,name');
define('value_product',':code,:name');
function AddNew($param_new)
{
$insert = $this->insert(tbl_all_product,field_product,value_product,$param_new);
}
```

**query.php**

```
public function insert($tbl, $field, $val, $param_new)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tbl." (".$field.") VALUES (".$val.")";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($param_new));
    }
```

and this information after debug

```
$tbl = "product";

$field = "code,name";

$val = ":code,:name";

$param_new = "':code' => 124,':name' => DELL";

$sql = "INSERT INTO product (code,name) VALUES (:code,:name)";

$query = PDOStatement#10 {
    "queryString" => "INSERT INTO product (code,name) VALUES (:code,:name)"
};
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the `param_new` wrong, here's why

```
$_POST['post_name'] = 'someName';

$param_new = "':code' =>124,':name' =>".$_POST['post_name']."";

print_r(array($param_new));

/*output
Array
(
    [0] => ':code' =>124,':name' =>someName
)
*/
```

This is what you eventually pass to `execute()`, an `array` with a single element, containing a comma delimited string.

Build `param_new` as an array from the beginning:

```
$_POST['post_name'] = 'someName';

$param_new = array(':code' => 124,':name' => $_POST['post_name']);

print_r($param_new);

/*output
Array
(
    [:code] => 124
    [:name] => someName
)
*/
```

and pass it over to `execute` as it is, not encapsulating it in another array

```
$query->execute($param_new);
```

Comment: how if the array is like this $param_new = array(2) {
    [:code] => 124
  , [:name] => someone
};

Comment: I don't understand your question, this is how an array of parameters being passed to `execute()` should look like. See example here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1024